# Cannot call one action from another in a React-Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a login modal. I use an action creator to turn isLoginModalVisible: true in the reducers. Calling the action creator inside a container, inside a component's onClick, like so:

```
<TextButtonRight onClick={()=> this.props.showLoginModal(true)}>
```

Inside the login modal, I have a login button that submits a form. I want the modal to disappear when 200OK otherwise, I display an error message in the modal. calling this action creator on login button click:

```
export function logInUser(){
    console.log("Actions--> logInUser");
    //Imagine I got a 200OK
    dispatch(showLoginModal(false));

    return({
        type: UPDATE_USER_LOGGED_IN,
        payload: true
    });
}
```

I'm calling the action creator to hide the modal from logInUser action creator and it's not working. The showLoginModal action creator does get hit but it does not dispatch to a reducer.

Here's the showLoginModal action creator:

```
export function showLoginModal(bool){
    console.log("Actions--> showLoginModal:"+bool);
    return({
        type: UPDATE_LOGIN_MODAL_VISIBLE,
        payload: bool
    });
}
```

(I'm sorry if I'm making a rookie mistake)

### Edit:

part of my reducer.It does work because that's how I show the login modal. I pass false when I want to hide it. There's no problem with the payload either. The console.log isn't getting get when I call it via another action creator. works okay when I pass it to onClick on submit button this way: 
`onClick={()=> this.props.showLoginModal(false)}`

```
case UPDATE_LOGIN_MODAL_VISIBLE:
            console.log("REDUCER-->"+UPDATE_LOGIN_MODAL_VISIBLE);
            return {...state, loginModalVisible: action.payload};
            break;
```

CombineReducers:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: postsReducer, 
    displayComps: displayComponentsReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    searchForm: searchFormReducer
});
```

### Edit 2:

Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using thunk. I wanted to know if there was a way to call an action from this one, like so:

```
req.then((response)=>{
    console.log("REQ_COMPLETE");
    dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_LOGGED_IN, payload: true});
    //like so:
    showLoginModal(false);
    localStorage.setItem('userLoggedIn', true);
 })
```

instead of adding this:

```
dispatch({type: UPDATE_LOGIN_MODAL_VISIBLE, payload: false});
```

dispatching the action from another action creator seemed kinda hacky.

Comment: Let's see your reducer code, especially combineReducers. That's the first place I would look if my reducer code isn't being hit. One technique that has helped me is to put a console log at the top of any reducer that you know is working and logging the action. That will tell you if it's being dispatched at all.

Comment: Also show full code of your ajax call. Async stuff can be tricky with Redux.

Comment: edited. @skypecakes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clarifying some terminology might help. Apologies in advance if this is stuff you already know.

When you want to dispatch multiple actions with redux-thunk, you dispatch an **operation**. That's a common pattern. It looks like your `logInUser()` function is an operation. For the canonical example, see `fetchPostsIfNeeded()` [in Dan Abramov's documentation here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.md#actionsjs-2).

An **action creator** simply returns an object and does nothing. An **operation** does stuff (often async) and then dispatches actions, which it generally builds by calling action creators. There's nothing hacky about dispatching actions from an operation.

However, calling any function from an **action creator** is not recommended. Action creators should return a simple object and have no side effects, like your `showLoginModal()` function. Note that there is **NO BEHAVIORAL DIFFERENCE** between calling an action creator and creating an object manually. So doing this:

`var action = { type: UPDATE_LOGIN_MODAL_VISIBLE, payload: false }`

is the same as

`var action = showLoginModal(false)`

Critical to note: Neither of these pieces of code does anything! They create an object but don't use it for anything. Nothing will happen in your app until you `dispatch(action)`.

#### Both action creators and operations must be `dispatch()`ed.

- The operation must be dispatched because that's how its inner function gets passed the `dispatch` function variable that it in turn uses to dispatch actions.
- Actions must be dispatched because they have no functionality of their own; they are just simple objects. Only when they are dispatched to the Redux store do they affect the store state.

It looks like this code of yours is calling an action creator but not dispatching it:

```
showLoginModal(false);
```

Changing that to

```
dispatch(showLoginModal(false));
```

might fix your issue.

It can be helpful to name action creators in a way that will help anyone reading the code (including you) to see/remember that they just create an action. For example you could rename `showLoginModal` to `showLoginModalAction` or even `createShowLoginModalAction`.

The `logInUser()` function is an operation (since it dispatches an action) that, for no clear reason, also returns an action. The action it returns is never dispatched to the store, at least in the code that is posted, so it would have no effect. Probably your intention is to dispatch that action to the store, so why not dispatch it right there?

```
logInUser(){
  dispatch( sendingLoginRequestAction() );
  someAsyncLoginFuncThatReturnsAPromise(userName, password)
  .then(result=>{
    dispatch( loginSucceededAction(result) );
    dispatch( hideLoginModalAction() );
  });
}
```

Those action creators would look like:

```
sendingLoginRequestAction() { return { type: UPDATE_SENDING_LOGIN_REQUEST }; } // You don't have anything like this, but it could be used to show a Waiting animation

loginSucceededAction() { return { type: UPDATE_USER_LOGGED_IN, payload: true }; }

hideDialogModalAction { return { type: UPDATE_LOGIN_MODAL_VISIBLE, payload: false }; }
```

Does that help?

Comment: thanks for the clarification! Since action creators should not have any side effects, would you suggest removing the dispatch(showLoginModal(false)) and handling it in the container itself?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I was dispatching the returned action in the container (mapDispatchToProps). Would it be better to dispatch all the actions in the operation itself and just dispatch single actions using mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: I think both are okay. It only really makes a difference in terms of reusability of the code. If you ever want to dispatch that operation *without* dispatching the action to close the dialog, then you'd want to do it outside the operation. Otherwise it seems cleaner to do everything in the operation. That way if you ever need to initiate logging in from some other component, it's one line of code.

Comment: If you do the dispatch separately, you will need to make sure your operation returns a Promise, and dispatch the dialog hide in the .then() block of the returned promise. That's another reason to do it in the operation.

Answer (score 5):

I think part of your problem is that you are not using Redux Middleware.
Here is a good tutorial from redux's creator himself: [Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux)

For your purposes, if you incorporate [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), you should be able to dispatch multiple actions from one action creator.

Here's how you can do it:

install:
`npm install --save redux-thunk`

put this in your `store.js` file

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Now, your action creator will have `dispatch` and `getState` available.

```
export const showLoginModal = (bool) => {
    console.log("Actions--> showLoginModal:"+bool);
    return({
        type: UPDATE_LOGIN_MODAL_VISIBLE,
        payload: bool
    });
}

export const loginUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log("Actions--> logInUser");
  // you have complete state available as getState(), but this is
  // not a good design pattern, so use with caution
  //Imagine I got a 200OK
  dispatch(showLoginModal(false));
  dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_USER_LOGGED_IN,
        payload: true
    });
}
```

I hope it helps. Have fun hacking.

Answer (score 4):

have you looked at [redux thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)? it lets you pass function to the reducers, which allow for async calling.

then in one of your action creators you could write something like:

```
export const logUserIn () => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(/* hit login url*/)
             .then(res => {/* switch on res here, if login worked
                              dispatch to hide modal, else show 
                              error*/})

    }
}
```

hope that helps a bit.